# We need a stock question on changing ip address to other subnet

Tags: discussion

[Connect to external host with/as local ip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378409/connect-to-external-host-with-as-local-ip) came up in the close que and it exposes a fundamental but common lack of understanding of how network routing works. It is undoubtedly a bad question, but unfortunately it is clear that the asker does not have the understanding to ask a good question.

I would like a canonical question on cross subnet address changes to point these folks to.

Comment: I was working on one for a general overview of networking. Very early draft is at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pTDrfsF8-80xaZta1UJLmTLjSyTea9yGdOWAZvZMSN0/edit ... which is editable by anyone with the link. But it probably needs a lot more work, and probably to be split into smaller parts.